# Error using fprintf and fscanf

Tags: c, string, windows, printf, scanf

I have an archive `results.csv` and I need to read the first line of this archive and print it out on `output.txt`. Somehow it's printing random characters after everything and I couldn't figure out what is wrong.

Command: `a.c results.csv`

First line:
`date,home_team,away_team,home_score,away_score,tournament,city,country,neutral`

output.txt: `date,home_team,away_team,home_score,away_score,tournament,city,country,neutral,(!£,(!£,(!£,(!£,(!£,@,£,(!£,(!£`

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <string.h>


typedef struct
{
    char *line1;
    char *line1a;
    char *line1b;
    char *team1;
    char *team2;
    char *reason;
    char *city;
    char *country;
    char *neutral_field;

}data;


void open_input(char *argv[], FILE **input)
{       

        if((*input=fopen(argv[1], "r")) == NULL)
        {
            printf("%s not found\n", argv[1]);
                exit(1);
        }

}
void open_output(char *string, FILE **output)
{       

        if((*output=fopen(string, "w")) == NULL)
        {
            printf("%s not found\n", string);
                exit(1);
        }

}

void alloc_data(data *d, int size)
{
d->line1 = (char*)malloc(4*sizeof(char)); 
d->team1 = (char*)malloc(9*sizeof(char)); 
d->team2 = (char*)malloc(9*sizeof(char)); 
d->line1a = (char*)malloc(10*sizeof(char)); 
d->line1b = (char*)malloc(10*sizeof(char)); 
d->reason = (char*)malloc(10*sizeof(char)); 
d->city = (char*)malloc(4*sizeof(char)); 
d->country = (char*)malloc(7*sizeof(char)); 
d->neutral_field = (char*)malloc(7*sizeof(char)); 
}

void store(data *d, FILE *input, FILE **output)
{

    fscanf(input,  "%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s", d[0].line1, d[0].team1, d[0].team2, d[0].line1a, d[0].line1b, d[0].reason, d[0].city, d[0].country, d[0].neutral_field );
    fprintf(*output,  "%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s\n", d[0].line1, d[0].team1, d[0].team2, d[0].line1a, d[0].line1b, d[0].reason, d[0].city, d[0].country, d[0].neutral_field );


}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    FILE *input;
    FILE *output;
    char *string = "output.txt";
    int size = 1000;

    open_input(argv, &input);   
    open_output(string, &output);   

    data *d;
    d = (data*)malloc(size*sizeof(data)); 
    alloc_data(d, size);

    store(d, input, &output);

    free(d);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `%c` is for printing `char`. `d[0].line1` (and others) is `char*`.

Comment: did you mean `%s` in the scanf for char array ? `%c` is for a single char.

Comment: And you're about to learn why `scanf()` is horrible.  Data read with a `scan()` format string can't be reliably printed via that same format string.

Comment: also use `%s` for printing the `char*` but here it could fail because the char array are not properly terminated

Comment: Also, do you really need `FILE **output` in function `store`? What's wrong with using `FILE *output`?

Comment: When reading/writing individual characters with `%c`, `fscanf()` should be passed the address of the character but, `fprintf()` should be passed the value.   Doing differently means one of the functions gives undefined behaviour.   The `fprintf()` calls are passing pointers to `%c` - that is undefined behaviour.

Comment: @AndrewHenle `scanf()` not used here.  True that `fscanf()` also shares some weakness of `scanf()`, but not as many.  OTOH `sscanf()` is yet another step up.  All parsing functions need careful application.

Comment: Okay so I´ve changed `%c` to `%s`, but it is still printing random characters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> `fscanf(input,  "%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s", d[0].line1, d[0].team1,...`

The above code tries to read the whole line in to `d[0].line1` which causes buffer overflow. `team1` and the rest will contain uninitialized data.

You have to change `fscanf` as follows:

```
fscanf(input, "%3[^ ,\n\t],%9[^ ,\n\t],...
```

Where 3 is 4 - 1, and 4 is the size of `d[0].line1`

Alternatively you can use `strtok`

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

void store(FILE *input, FILE *output)
{
    char buf[500];
    while(fgets(buf, sizeof(buf), input))
    {
        //strip end-of-line from `buf`
        if(strlen(buf))
            if(buf[strlen(buf) - 1] == '\n')
                buf[strlen(buf) - 1] = 0;

        //tokenize with strtok
        char *token = strtok(buf, ",");
        while(token)
        { 
            fprintf(output, "%s", token);
            token = strtok(NULL, ",");
        }
        fprintf(output, "\n");
    }
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    FILE *input = fopen("input.txt", "r");
    FILE *output = fopen("output.txt", "w");
    store(input, output);
    return 0;
}
```

With above code you don't need an additional structure.

---

If you do use a structure for data, you have to be more careful. It seems you are trying to create an array of 1000 `data`, but the following only creates one oversized pointer, not an array of `data`

```
int size = 1000;
data *d;
d = (data*)malloc(size*sizeof(data)); 
alloc_data(d, size);
```

Additionally, for each `malloc` there should be a corresponding `free`.

Answer (score 1):

Your buffers aren't big enough to hold the terminating NUL byte.  `scanf` stores that NUL byte (overrunning the buffer), but then the object that really owns that byte may overwrite it, so when `printf` looks for the NUL it doesn't find it until much later in memory.

The buffer overruns are a bigger problem than what you've seen, who knows what objects those NUL bytes you didn't make space for are smashing?  And what happens when you read a data file with slightly different header spelling?  Suddenly your hard-coded allocations sizes will be even more wrong than they are already.