# Splitting a long string

Tags: c, string, split, scanf, archive

I have an archive `results.csv` and I need to read the first two lines of this archive, split the second one and print them out on `output.txt`. Somehow it's not printing anything, yet I don't know the reason.

I didn't add the functions that I'm sure are fine.

Command: `a.c results.csv`

First line:
`date,home_team,away_team,home_score,away_score,tournament,city,country,neutral`

Second line:
`18721130,Scotland,England,0,0,Friendly,Glasgow,Scotland,FALSE`

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct
{
    char *line1;
    long int date;
    char *h_team;
    char *a_team;
    int gols_h_team;
    int gols_a_team;
    char *reason;
    char *city;
    char *country;
    char *neutral_field;

}Data;

void alloc_Data(Data *d, int size)
{
d->line1 = (char*)malloc(50*sizeof(char)); 
d->h_team = (char*)malloc(30*sizeof(char)); 
d->a_team = (char*)malloc(30*sizeof(char)); 
d->reason = (char*)malloc(30*sizeof(char)); 
d->city = (char*)malloc(30*sizeof(char)); 
d->country = (char*)malloc(30*sizeof(char)); 
d->neutral_field = (char*)malloc(9*sizeof(char)); 
}

void store(Data *d, FILE *input, FILE *output, int size)
{

    fscanf(input,  "%s", d[0].line1);
    fprintf(output,  "%s\n", d[0].line1);

    for(int i = 1; i < size; i++)
    {
        fscanf(input, "%li,%[^,]s%[^,]s%d,%d,%[^,]s%[^,]s%[^,]s%[^,]s", &d[i].date, d[i].h_team, d[i].a_team, &d[i].gols_h_team, &d[i].gols_a_team, d[i].reason, d[i].city, d[i].country, d[i].neutral_field );
        fprintf(output, "%li,%s,%s,%d,%d,%s,%s,%s,%s\n", d[i].date, d[i].h_team, d[i].a_team, d[i].gols_h_team, d[i].gols_a_team, d[i].reason, d[i].city, d[i].country, d[i].neutral_field );

    }

}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    FILE *input;
    FILE *output;
    char *string = "output.txt";
    int size = 2;

    open_input(argv, &input);   
    open_output(string, &output);   

    Data *d;
    d = (Data*)malloc(size*sizeof(Data)); 
    alloc_Data(d, size);

    store(d, input, output, size);

    free(d);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please don't omit functions which work, because they may not. But more important, store the result of scanf and ensure that it is the one you expect. And use a debugger.

Comment: Ere you expecting `%[^,]s` to be some sort of regular expression parser? because scanf isn't regex.

Comment: `d[0].line1` is only 50 bytes long, but the first line of the file is 78 characters.

Comment: If you allocate fixed amounts for your strings, why not have arrays? Especially since you don't free the strings you allocate.

Comment: `"%li,%[^,]s%[^,]...` will not parse pass `"%li,%[^,]"`.  It will always fail to match `s`.  `s` never follows non-`,`.

Comment: Tip:  "I don't know the reason." --> check the return values of input functions like `fscanf()`.  What is as expected?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error using fprintf and fscanf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50743661/error-using-fprintf-and-fscanf)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OP's `fscanf()` format is messed up with an `s` after `%[^,]` and missing `,`.  [@Gem Taylor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50745686/spliting-a-long-string/50746343#comment88499373_50745686)

A better alternative is to read *all* lines using `fgets()`.  (including the first)

```
// fscanf(input, "%li,%[^,]s%[^,]s%d,%d,%[^,]s%[^,]s%[^,]s%[^,]s",...d[i].neutral_field );

#define EXPECTED_MAX_BUFFER_SIZE 150
char buffer[EXPECTED_MAX_BUFFER_SIZE * 2];  // suggest using 2x expected max size
if (fgets(buffer, sizeof buffer, input)) {
```

Then parse the team results with `sscanf()`.  Using a `" %n"` at the end is an easy way to test if the entire `sscanf()` succeeded with no extra junk.  `sscanf()` deserve width limits and complex scans benefit with some defines to manage the specifiers.  Notice no `s` after `"%29[^,]"`

```
    int n = 0;
    #define FDat "%li ,"
    #define FScr "%d ,"
    #define Ftxt " %29[^,],"
    #define Fneu " %8[^,]"
    sscanf(buffer, FDat Ftxt Ftxt FScr FScr Ftxt Ftxt Ftxt Fneu " %n", 
        &d[i].date, d[i].h_team, d[i].a_team, 
        &d[i].gols_h_team, &d[i].gols_a_team, 
        d[i].reason, d[i].city, d[i].country, d[i].neutral_field, &n);

    if (n > 0 && buffer[n] == '\0') {
      // success
      fprintf(output, ...
    } else {
      // bad input
    }
```